# k-prototypes with stable results

Tags: python, cluster-analysis

I am using k-prototypes from k modes package based on python.
As K-means,[k-prototypes] exports different results every time.

In K-modes, we could set random_state for getting stable results, how can i do the same thing for k-prototypes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this function call, `init` parameter can be `huang`, `cao` and `random`:

```
def k_prototypes_single(Xnum, Xcat, nnumattrs, ncatattrs, n_clusters, n_points,
                        max_iter, num_dissim, cat_dissim, gamma, init, init_no,
                        verbose, random_state):
```

Changing it to anything but `random` might help.

On the other hand, `np.random.seed(42)` might help as well, since most likely the author is using `np.random()`

Comment: Thank you, lenik. I am using Cao for init, but the result still changing every time.my code:  kproto = KPrototypes(n=clusters=3, init=`Cao`)  clusters=kproto.fit=predict(data,categorical=[4])